# How to make react-native-elements Tooltip size dynamic based on its content?

Tags: react-native, tooltip, react-native-elements

The React Native Elements Tooltip ([docs here](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/tooltip.html)) requires you to pass in the `width` and `height` property for the tooltip, but I want to create a generic tooltip button that can receive any element as its `popover` prop.

The following example is what I have, but it uses the default size set to the tooltip by the React Native Element library:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Tooltip } from 'react-native-elements'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Container = styled.View`
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #aaf;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
`

const Icon = styled.Text``

export default function TooltipButton({ tooltip }) {
  return (
    <Tooltip popover={tooltip}>
      <Container>
        <Icon>?</Icon>
      </Container>
    </Tooltip>
  )
}
```

When the content is bigger than the default size it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ4VQ.png).

I Don't want to have to pass a fixed size as prop to this component, I would like it to have a tooltip size depending on it's content.

Comment: Have you try add `flex:1` in style? [Flex](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#flex) would resize to fit the parent or container?

Comment: If you could post some part of your code will be more easier to help you.

Comment: @高鵬翔 do you mean flex:1 in the popover element container? That didn't work.

Comment: Added the code I had before changing it to how it looks like in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

After some time trying to figure this out, I managed to do a somewhat autosize tooltip button that receives a content element as a prop (tooltip) and resizes itself based on its content.

The only way I got it to work properly was to set an initial size bigger than the content (500x500) and add more size to it (+30).

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Tooltip } from 'react-native-elements'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Container = styled.View`
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #aaf;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
`

const Icon = styled.Text``

export default function TooltipButton({ tooltip }) {
  const [tooltipSize, setTooltipSize] = useState({ w: 500, h: 500 })

  const tooltipClone = React.cloneElement(
    tooltip,
    { onLayout: (e) => setTooltipSize({ w: e.nativeEvent.layout.width, h: e.nativeEvent.layout.height }) }
  )

  return (
    <Tooltip 
      popover={tooltipClone} 
      width={tooltipSize.w + 30} 
      height={tooltipSize.h + 30}
    >
      <Container>
        <Icon>?</Icon>
      </Container>
    </Tooltip>
  )
}
```

End result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuIEf.png).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the component! Do you know the reason why it is necessary to increase the width and height (+30) and to set an initial size bigger than the content??

Comment: @VictorMolina no idea, I got to this by doing a lot of experimentation =/

Answer (score 2):

It seems that using null forces height and width to take as much space as the contents need!

```js
height={null} // using height={null} seems to look good
width={null} // using width={200} seems to look better than null
```

Source of this hint: [ToolTip in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67861258/tooltip-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's enough to add 20 units to width and height. That's required because the default style applied to the Tooltip component adds a padding of 10, see [here](https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements/blob/next/src/tooltip/Tooltip.tsx#L156).